# How to run a server side php file in J2ME

Tags: java-me, client-server

I am developing a server-client application with using J2ME. There I need the client program to access the server and view data. For doing this, I made an HTTP connection with the server. Now I want to run a php file which is located in server and doing the needful. But I couldn't able to find a way to run the server php file using my client app. Please anyone can help on this ?

Comment: I mean that I want to run a php which is in the localhost(the server), and which is able to read, update the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right the solution is as follows:

1. Implement a php-script that gets POST or GET request and save it in a file. For instance: "yourscript.php". This script does what is necessary and generates the output, let say in plain text format.
2. Implement a J2ME functionality that opens HTTPConnection and [makes POST or GET request](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/SampletodemonstrateHttpGETandPOSTfromMIDlet.htm) to http://www.yourserver.com/yourscript.php (according to your php-script expectations) and reads the server response.

That's it.